linux KVM host, no network connection on guest VMs
after a kernel upgrade with out debian servers we went through reboots and have since then problems with obe of our KVM hosts. On the host itself everything works, but on the guests there is no network connection. No ping/traceroute from them to the host or anywhere else possible. And same way around no ping/traceroute possible.
KVM Host:
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1np0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:d0:9d:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0f0np0
    inet 172.23.1.18/24 brd 172.23.1.255 scope global eno1np0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3eec:efff:fed0:9dac/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2np1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:d0:9d:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0f1np1
4: enxbe3af2b6059f: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether be:3a:f2:b6:05:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
20: br10: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2e:36:d3:a9:cd:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
21: br231: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:22:29:25:0a:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

ip l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1np0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:d0:9d:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0f0np0
3: eno2np1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:d0:9d:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0f1np1
4: enxbe3af2b6059f: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether be:3a:f2:b6:05:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
20: br10: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2e:36:d3:a9:cd:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
21: br231: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:22:29:25:0a:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


brctl show
    bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
    br10            8000.2e36d3a9cd95       no
    br231           8000.f62229250ab6       no

cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eno1np0
iface eno1np0 inet static
        address 172.23.1.18/24
        gateway 172.23.1.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 172.23.1.2
        dns-search intern.domain

# via bridges in vms durchgereichte netzwerkinterfaces

auto enp129s0f0.10
iface enp129s0f0.10 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device enp129s0f0

auto br10
iface br10 inet manual
    bridge_ports enp129s0f0.10

auto enp129s0f0.231
iface enp129s0f0.231 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device enp129s0f0

auto br231
iface br231 inet manual
    bridge_ports enp129s0f0.231


what's the point of the two bridges on the host with no interfaces? You say you have issues with "one of our KVM hosts" - how does the network configuration differ on the non-working one with the working KVM hosts?

The working ones are configured in a different way. Aka they are not internal but hosted on a cloud provider outside of our internal network.
Yes regarding the bridges with no interfaces was also the only indication I had, but I never worked with bridges and vnets before so I struggled to see the solution.
It seems we solved the issue btw., the problem are the interface names, they got changed (FOR WHATEVER REASON, I wonder if anyone has an idea how this can happen without user interaction?).
enp129s0f0 doesn't exist as an interface.

I don't understand why you have br10 and br231 on the host AND the VM - is that just your naming scheme? they aren't related you know

I didn't post any information of the VM. All this is data from the host.
Btw little correction to what I said earlier about the problem being fixed, apparently booting back to Kernel Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64 x86_64 instead of "26" and now everything works again...still trying to find official issues in this regard.

Oh, sorry, didn't understand what via bridges in vms durchgereichte netzwerkinterfaces means as I don't speak whatever non-english language that is

No worries, that is just still a part of the previous mentioned /etc/network/interfaces
